# When using C# WebDriver, can one disable IE native events?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am having lots of issues with C# WebDriver not performing click events when it doesn't have focus.

This is because the [InternetExplorerDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) uses native events which is must have true focus, otherwise it will just silently fail.

So, is it possible to completely disable native events for IE, similar to what can be done using Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# binding the NuGet package 'Selenium.WebDriver' (I'm using version 2.48.2) offers the following

```
var internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions {
                  IgnoreZoomLevel = true, 
                  EnableNativeEvents = false
               };
var driver = new new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions);
```

This solved the issue in our dev env.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible at the moment. Currently, you could use JavaScript instead of using `WebElement.click()`. An implementation allowing you to disable native events in IE is forthcoming, but I can offer no timeframe for its availability.

Comment: What about Google Chrome? Is there a way to disable native events?